# Why is my C program for finding factorials up to 21 producing invalid results starting at the factorial for 13?

Tags: c

At the iteration for calculating the factorial for 13 it starts to produce invalid results. I have typed this up exactly the way it is written in my textbook but I am getting a different output then what is listed in the book. My compiler is Dev C++ and its set to the C99 standard. Is there some setting that is off in the compiler that would cause unsigned long long ints to not format correctly or not have the appropriate max value? At 13! it prints 1932053504.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//prototype for factorial function
unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned int number);

int main(void){
    unsigned int i; //counter for for-loop

    //during each iteration call factorial and print result
    for( i = 0; i <= 21; ++i){
        printf("%u! = %11u\n", i, factorial(i));
    }
}

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned int number){
    if(number <= 1){
        return 1;
    }
else{ //recursive step
    return(number * factorial(number - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you asking for it?  Look at the `printf` format modifiers you are using.

Comment: Just to let you know: your *IDE* is Dev-C++, not your compiler. They are both different things.

Comment: Not the answer but: As factorial is a recursive function that uses the result of factorial as argument both its return type and argument type should be the same to avoid possible casting problems, `unsigned int` usually will be smaller than `unsigned long long int`.

Also 13! is more than 32bits long and the C standard do not give a warranty that `unsigned int` or even `unsigned long long int` would be greater than 32 bits (in fact there is no mention to the actual size of any integer type other than char).

Comment: @Fernando The C standard does imply that `long long` is at least 64-bit.

Comment: @YuHao you are right. `long long int` is at least 64 bits and `int` is at least 16 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your specifier. I think you meant `ll` not `11`. You're passing a `unsigned long long` to it so it needs to be

```
printf("%u! = %llu\n", i, factorial(i));
```

This is another reason to turn on (and pay attention to) compiler warnings. My compiler told me straight away what the problem was.

```
test.c:11:35: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'unsigned long long' [-Wformat]
        printf("%u! = %11u\n", i, factorial(i));
                      ~~~~        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                      %11llu
1 warning generated.
```

The answer you've been getting is the result of undefined behavior but your machine being little endian, having 32 bit ints, 13! = 6227020800 > 2^32 = 4294967296 and that 6227020800 % 4294967296 = 1932053504 may have been the reasons why you were getting that answer.